# Why can't I increment partition size with cfdisk?

Tags: partitioning, fdisk

This is an screenshot of cfdisk, showing that I have 20G of free space. When I try to resize /dev/sda2 to just 12G I get an error saying that I have not enough space. (10197402624 bytes == 10G).

[image]

However, when I try with the "Disks" app...

[image]

[image]

[image]

It doesn't complain and everything works as expected. What is wrong with cfdisk? The same thing happens when I use fdisk.

Comment: The free space is clearly on the other side of sda 5 therefore you would have to move it out of the way to expand the partition. The chance of data lost will become quite high.

Comment: Sorry @David but I don't understand what you mean.